# NoClassDefFoundError on Android release build

Tags: android, proguard, dagger-2, android-proguard, dagger

I'm using Dagger 2 and proguard, and one of my users gets a NoClassDefFoundError when he attempts to open the app after installing from the PlayStore. He's using KitKat, Samsung TabS. I'm at a loss here. What could be going wrong?

Here are my dependencies:

```
compile rootProject.ext.kotlinStdLib

kapt rootProject.ext.dataBindingCompiler

compile rootProject.ext.cardView
compile rootProject.ext.design
compile rootProject.ext.appCompat

compile rootProject.ext.hockeyApp

compile rootProject.ext.rxAndroid

compile rootProject.ext.everNoteJob
compile rootProject.ext.gpsServices

compile rootProject.ext.dagger
kapt rootProject.ext.daggerCompiler
provided rootProject.ext.javax

compile rootProject.ext.retrofit
compile rootProject.ext.retrofitRxJava
compile rootProject.ext.retrofitGson

compile rootProject.ext.okHttp
debugCompile rootProject.ext.okHttpLogger
debugCompile rootProject.ext.leakCanary

compile rootProject.ext.rxJava2

testCompile rootProject.ext.junit
testCompile rootProject.ext.assertj
testCompile rootProject.ext.mockitoKotlin
testCompile rootProject.ext.roboElectric
testCompile rootProject.ext.kotlinStdLib

androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.mockitoKotlin
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.kotlinReflect
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.kotlinStdLib
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.espresso
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.espressoIntents
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.espressoTestRunner
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.findBugs
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.dexMaker
androidTestCompile rootProject.ext.uiAutomator
```

And their versions:

```
buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"

jdkVersion = '1.8'

minSdkVersion = 19

targetSdkVersion = 25

compileSdkVersion = 25

kotlinStdLib = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:${kotlin_version}"
kotlinReflect = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlin_version}"

androidSupportVersion = '25.4.0'
daggerVersion = '2.9'

hockeyApp = "net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.3"
appCompat = "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"
design = "com.android.support:design:${androidSupportVersion}"
cardView = "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${androidSupportVersion}"
dagger = "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
rxAndroid = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
javax = "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"
dataBindingCompiler = "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_plugin_version"
threeTenAbp = "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5"
everNoteJob = "com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11"
gpsServices = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1"
leakCanary = "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1"

retrofitVersion = '2.2.0'
okhttpVersion = '3.7.0'

retrofit = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
retrofitRxJava = "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofitVersion}"
retrofitGson = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"
okHttp = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okhttpVersion}"
okHttpLogger = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okhttpVersion}"
rxJava2 = "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0"

powerMockVersion = '2.0.0-beta.5'

junit = "junit:junit:4.12"
mockitoKotlin = "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
assertj = "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.6.2"
roboElectric = "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2"

espresso = "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1"
espressoIntents = "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1"
espressoIdler = "com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.0.0"
espressoTestRunner = "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1"
dexMaker = "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0"
uiAutomator = "com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3"
findBugs = "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace?

Comment: Is multidex enabled?

Comment: Stacktrace is the NoClassDefFound error.

Comment: And yes, multidex is enabled in the build.gradle file

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace? What particular class failed to be loaded?
Please tell some more details as now there is not enough information in order to solve your problem.